# Kendo UI Grid, sorting datasource groups

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a page that has a Kendo grid on it. 
It is calling an ajaz web request to get its data.
Once the data has been returned it is grouped in the frontend. 
The problem I am having is sorting the groups. What is the best way to do this?

My MVC view code looks something like this...

```
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Group(groups =>
        {
            groups.Add(c => c.groupingField);
        })
        .Read(...))
```

I have tried to use the [sort](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-sort) method but am not sure where to put it when the data is coming from an ajax call.

Comment: It's not JavaScript ;)

Comment: Thanks, I've removed the JS reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that adding the below line to the datasource call solved my problem...

```
  .Sort(sort => sort.Add("FIELD_NAME").Ascending())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide groups in correct order in .Group() method. I don't have mvc version installed but for example it should be ok:

```
 var groupList = new List<string> { "Gr1", "Gr2" };

.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Group(groups =>
    {
        groupList.Select(x => groups.Add(x));
    })
    .Read(...))
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Adding more than one field to the group will add another grouping. I need to order the first group by another field in the group. How would I add an 'orderby'?